# How to jump to a point using CharacterController?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script to jump, but it jumps depending on the value of the JumpFactor constant. I would like the jump to happen using the JumpToPositionX (float target) method. I think I need to somehow calculate the JumpFactor depending on the value of the target in the JumpToPositionX method. I found an article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Conditions_at_an_arbitrary_distance_x), but I don't even know where to start. I have not found examples of how to do this with the CharacterController.

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    const float Speed = 6f;
    const float JumpFactor = 14f;
    const float Gravity = 20f;
    
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    CharacterController controller;

    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f); // Move X Direction
            moveDirection *= Speed;
            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
                moveDirection.y = JumpFactor;

        }
        moveDirection.y -= Gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    // Method for jump, calling from other script.
    void JumpToPositionX(float target)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Theory**

I assume you want to use the ballistic physic.

Let's see what formula we can use

[image: speedFormula]

[image: positionFormula]

Where :

- V : Velocity
- a : Acceleration
- P : Position
- t : time since start
- 0 : Initial

[image] is known it's `(0f,-9.81f)` or `(0f, Gravity)` in your case.

[image] is known too, it's your initial position before the jump.

[image] is the end target position.

[image]

**Resolution**

You have to find the end time [image] and the initial Velocity [image]. So here's the position equation:

[image]

We can simplify the process by looking only for the x axis because there's no acceleration.
[image]

is simplified to : [image]

Let's isolate the [image] from the x position formula :
[image]

Now you have the total time of the jump [image].
You just need to find the initial y velocity [image] by using the y position formula :

[image]

Isolate the Vyo :
[image]

So now you have all informations for computing the jump : Initial and end position, Total time, Initial velocity and acceleration.

**Implementation**

Here's an example of the MonoBehaviour you can create :

```
public class JumpBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController CharacterController;

    public Transform TargetPosition;

    private bool jumpStarted = false;
    private float totalTime = 0f;
    private float t = 0f;
    private Vector2 V0;

    private Vector2 initialPosition;

    private bool jumpKeyDown;

    private const float xSpeed = 6f;
    private const float gravity = -9.81f;

    void Update()
    {
        jumpKeyDown = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (jumpStarted)
        {
            UpdateJumpPosition(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
        else if (jumpKeyDown )
        {
            StartJump();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateJumpPosition(float deltaTime)
    {
        t += deltaTime;

        if(t > totalTime)
        {
            //End of jump
            transform.position = TargetPosition.position;
            jumpStarted = false;
            return;
        }

        Vector2 newPosition = new Vector2(0f, gravity) * t * t + V0 * t + initialPosition;

        CharacterController.Move(newPosition);
    }

    private void StartJump()
    {
        jumpStarted = true;

        initialPosition = transform.position;

        // Absolute because xSpeed could be positive or negative. We dont want negative time
        float delta = TargetPosition.position.x - transform.position.x;
        totalTime = Mathf.Abs(delta / xSpeed);
        t = 0f;

        float yInitialSpeed = (TargetPosition.position.y - transform.position.y - gravity * totalTime * totalTime) / totalTime;

        // Using Sign to set the direction of horizontal movement
        V0 = new Vector2(xSpeed * Mathf.Sign(delta), yInitialSpeed);
    }
}
```

And this is the result
[image: unity result]

**Conclusion**

This is just an quick example to figure out how to compute the initial value of the jump and movement in 2D.
As derHugo said on comment you should not use `transform.position` direct attribution with Physic.

For 3D it's the same idea but you should compute the speed x,z from target direction and speed magnitude.

```
Vector3 delta = TargetPosition - transform.position;
delta.y = 0f;
float direction = delta.normalized;
Vector3 initialSpeed = direction * movementSpeed;
```

Comment: This is nice and fine .. **BUT** whenever there is any `Rigidbody` (physics) involved in Unity you should **NOT** change or access any values via the `Transform` component (which you are doing in `transform.position = newPosition;`). This breaks the physics and all collision detection and thereby the entire purpose of the `CharacterController` ;) What you want to do is rather go through the `controller.Move` method

Comment: Yes. It's just a simple example if no physic is involve. Otherwise he/she should adapt how gameObject is moved but at least he/she has the formula to compute the position overtime and the initial velocity.

Comment: @derHugo I edited to add more information. Do you think it's better ?

Comment: since the question is directly related to the physics engine and CharacterController, yes, I'ld say it is quite relevant ;)

Comment: You are right. I'll maybe add an example with the CharacterController.

Comment: just replace update() with FixedUpdate() and increase the rigidbody drag to maximum value so it can collide but not move because of collisions or gravity without acessing the transform.

Comment: I updated my answer to use the `CharacterController` and the `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: @D.B note that you should still get User input (`GetKeyDown`) only in `Update` since it can not be guaranteed that it is still valid in the `FixedUpdate` call ;) Also I would still get the position via `var xyz = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position` and set it via `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(xyz);` in order to not break the physics ;) .. of course you cache the `Rigidbody` reference as usual

Comment: But if he/she want to use a characterController he/she could use the `CharacterController.Move()` method ? I thought `CharacterController` is handeling the rigidbody on its `Move` method. Otherwise you are right for the `GetKeyDown`

Comment: @D.B, Can I use it in Update() method instead of FixedUpdate()?

Comment: @AimonZ. You should use `FixedUpdate` for all physic related call. But `Update` for `Input ` read stuff. Why do you prefer `Update` on your case?

Comment: @D.B, The Unity documentation uses CharacterContorller.Move () in Update() https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html

Comment: @AimonZ. You are right. Try to use it on `Update` method. It looks like `CharacterController.Move` take care of collision.